# Disable outlook "propose new time" button by iCalendar vEvent

Tags: java, outlook, ms-office, icalendar, ical4j

I have a specific question. I sent out iCalendar files by the library [iCal4j](http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Main_Page) but now I need that the receiver of the iCalendar can't propose a new time. So the button *'propose new time'* nee te bo disabled.

When I sent out a meeting request from 2010 and disable the option 'Allow New Time Proposals' then the property **X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER** is set to **true**. This option seems to work with outlook 2010 but isn't accept by outlook 2007.

Does someone have an idea for a other property setting?
[image]

iCal4j code:

```
//add property so ms outlook knows that the users can't propose a new time
XProperty xprop = new XProperty("X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER","TRUE");
vEvent.getProperties().add(xprop);
```

**Edit** 
It seems that outlook 2007 also use X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:TRUE to disable the button, but unfortunately this isn't accepted on the client's exchange server.

Answer (score 2):

Searching the [iCalendar RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), I did not find anything about disabling the option to reschedule an event; that seems sensible - any recipient could override a "no reschedule" marker by issuing a new event, so the users are going to have to abide by some social contract regardless.

Your Outlook 2010 solution clearly relies on something internal to MS Outlook, and which I doubt would be respected by any other program that uses the iCalendar format.

Relative to disabling reschedule for Outlook 2007 only, I did not see anything in a cursory search.  If you have access to 2007, why not try the same technique you used to look at the 2010 events?

Comment: yeah it is not in the iCalendar RFC because it is a special outlook thing. but outlook also works with X properties...